# How do I grep for all words that are more than 6 characters and without any vowel letters?

Tags: regex, grep

I found that this could specify a certain length
 grep -o -w '\w{6,10}' data

But I want to find all the words which contains 6 or more than 6 letter and with no any vowel letters.

Comment: Regular `grep` does not generally accept neither the Perl escape code `\w` nor the extended regular expression repetition operator `{6,10}`.  With POSIX `grep` you could say `grep -o -w '[[:alnum:]]\{6,10\}' data` for roughly the intended results.

Comment: If it's a Welsh dictionary you are checking, just print every line :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***grep*** approach to find all the words(alphanumeric sequences) containing 6 or more letters except ***vowels***:

*data* file contents:

```
some text with vowels and CNN_tvs chars swwwdfrgcc done ...
```

---

```
grep -Eio '\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z0-9_]{6,}\b' data
```

The output:

```
CNN_tvs
swwwdfrgcc
```

---

`\b` - points to word boundary

`b-df-hj-np-tv-z` - the range of consonant letters

---

alternative ***perl*** approach:

```
perl -nle 'print for /\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z0-9_]{6,}\b/gi' data
```

Comment: @l'L'l, no, `E` is a good option, it'll cover both GNU and BSD implementations

Comment: Confirmed working with `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`, and `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`+

Comment: Thank you. it works. Can anyone explain what that '\b' exactly means?

Answer (score -1):

You could combine all your requirement in one single regex.

> ^(?i)[^aeiouy]{6,10}$
>
> Explanation : ^  means at the beginning means that there can't be
> anything before the pattern. The string as to begin with the pattern.
> (?i) means being case insensitive. [^aeiouy] are strings that do not
> contains vowels (not is ^) {6,10} is {minlenght, maxlenght) $ means
> there can't be anything after the match

Use it in your grep.

Comment: You cannot use Perl extensions with `grep` unless your version implements the nonstandard `-P` option.

Comment: It's also matching 6 or more non-word characters.